# How to get back my hard-earned tag badges

Tags: discussion, support, badges

I have experienced a weird problem here.

My profile on main is [SubarshaB](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/294365/subarshab).

I had earned many badges notably the rare ones like [linear-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra), [real-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis), [abstract-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra).

Today I found all my tag badges are gone.

I checked my profile and it said I only have an answer score of 1/100 in [real-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis) and so on.

How can I get my tag badges back?

Comment: Although tag badges are quite rare, those are actually three of the four most common tag badges. You're missing the most common tag badge, (calculus) That badge has been awarded 430 times at this time of posting. For a list, see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It appears that you had a couple accounts merged very recently, on 2017-03-25 at 07:23:40Z to be precise, which is less than an hour ago as I am typing this. It appears that the account that got merged into the current one had about 11K rep, and before the merge *this* account had about 2800 rep. In particular, I bet that prior to the merge *this* account didn't have any tag badges.

Unlike other badges, tag badges are awarded (and retracted) by a daily script that runs at about 03:00Z which calculates your tag scores. If you are eligible for a new tag badge, it is awarded; if you no longer meet the requirements of a tag badge, it is retracted. (See Meta Stack Exchange: [What are tag badges? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63835))

When profiles are merged, the tag scores are apparently not re-calculated, and because prior to the merge *this* account didn't have these tag badges, it continues to not have them. (If the merge went in the other direction, then the tag badges should have been retained.) But when the script next runs, your tag scores should be corrected and any tag badges "lost" should be returned. If this doesn't happen, then you should be more concerned.

Comment: Yeah. If you wait about 17 hours or so the script will run again, and all the tag scores should be correctly updated. As for undoing the merge: probably not. I'm trying to make sense of your account history, and I'll probably ping a CM to be certain, but it seems you contacted the SE team about recovering an account, and the merge was probably in response to that. I am not privy to whatever messages you sent to/received from the SE team, but that's my interpretation of what I can see.

Comment: @SubarshaB "Can this merge be undone?" What for?

Comment: Lol, I always felt like those tag badges weren't updated automatically, and now I know!

Comment: @Mathematics Did you get the tag badges back? *(checks profile)* Yep, looks like you did!