# unable to change email address

Tags: support

I need to change the email address in my profile, which I also use
for logging in.

I found a black square aside of it. I tried all the same and regularly got authentication msg and proceeded with that. However the change did not take effect.

*Update*: I now see the new address below the old in my profile, as in this snapshot

[image: login_1]

However I cannot log in through it (I get error warning), and I can only through the old one.
I mean that I log out, clean personal data on browser, try and log in afresh giving again address+password.

How can I manage that ? thanks for the attention and help

Comment: Explain what you mean by "the change did not take effect".  For example: you logged out, removed cookies involving stackexchange.com from your browser, and tried logging back in with the new email?

Comment: @GEdgar: thanks for your reply. Yes, I did like you indicated, and repeated that just now. I have added some more details in my post. Can you suggest a way to solve/further investigate the problem ? Anything to do with the fact that the new address appears under "Other(?)" and what is that? thanks

Comment: In the worst case I think creating a new account with the email address you want, then going through the process to [request a merger of accounts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26100/is-it-possible-to-merge-accounts-of-different-users).  The difficulty is in proving to the satisfaction of Powers That Be that you control both accounts.

Comment: @hardmath: tanks for the suggestion, but before going along such a risky way, I would like to try others. Any other hint that you can provide?

Comment: Another hint... switch to an OpenId provider as a means of logging in, rather than having a password (known to StackExchange) associated with an email address as your userid.  See [How do I add or remove login credentials from my account?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/edit-credentials), which also has a link to [the account recovery tool](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery).